# C# Double Nullable with MySQL INSERT

Tags: c#, mysql, class, null, double

I have the following class;

```
public class Hotel
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double? MinRate {get;set;}
    public double? MaxRate {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see the value for either MinRate or MaxRate can be null.  I'm using the following code to get the data from the List of Hotel classes;

```
var HotelList = 
       String.Join(",", Hotel.Select(m => String.Format("('{0}','{1}','{2}')",
       MySqlHelper.EscapeString(m.Name),  m.MinRate, m.MaxRate)));
```

This works fine.  The HotelList variable will be used with a MySQL INSERT statement like

```
INSERT INTO Hotels (Name,MinRate,MaxRate) VALUES 
(ABC Hotel','125','199'),('DEF','','');
```

The problem I have is that sometimes the value of MinRate or MaxRate can be null, which is handled in the class.  But for the MySQL INSERT statement I need to set the value to null somehow, since I'm getting the error

Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'MinRate' at row 5

Any ideas how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Make the column nullable then.

Comment: I did, but since the code currently formats the values like '' it doesnt appear to work

Comment: you mean you actuall have to say NULL in your insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your nullable types have a value with HasValue:

```
var HotelList = 
       String.Join(",", Hotel.Select(m => String.Format("('{0}',{1},{2})",
       MySqlHelper.EscapeString(m.Name),  m.MinRate.HasValue?("'"+m.MinRate.Value.ToString()+"'"):"NULL", m.MaxRate.HasValue?("'"+m.MaxRate.Value.ToString()+"'"):"NULL")));
```

Said that, it is always better to use query parameters to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Would you not consider doing this check in the class when the value is set ?

Answer (score 0):

if you really wnat to set it in clss you can modify your getters and seeter like so I think

```
 public double? MinRate {get;set;}

  public string MinRateString  
   {
         get {
                if(MinRate!=null)
                   return MinRate.ToString();
                 else
                   return "Null";
            }
   }
```

then use the  MinRateString when inserting